# Interpreting Changes in Software Energy Consumption During the Day: Seeking Insight on Patterned Peaks and Valleys

Tags: noise, reactive-power

My group and I are currently studying the energy consumption of software as part of our master's degree in computer science. Specifically, we are looking at how to measure it accurately and interpret the data. During our research, we observed that the energy measurements seemed to change slightly based on the time of day. To further investigate this issue, we conducted a 24-hour cycle measurement of the computer with hardware measurements.

We created the plot below based on our findings. Although it's still missing some data, we can clearly see that the energy consumption rises during the day (except the start of the blue part, as it was running a benchmark) and falls during the night. Additionally, we noticed a consistent pattern of peaks and valleys that are uniformly spaced.

[image]

We believe that the rise and fall of energy consumption during the day could be due to electrical noise on the network, which might cause a worse power factor?. However, we are puzzled by the cause of the pattern of peaks and valleys.
We want to seek insights and guidance on this matter since it goes beyond our domain of knowledge. Any input or feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Is our hypothesis of what cause rise and fall of energy consumption during the day plausible?

Is the and is the a good explanation for the pattern?(already answered)

Comment: What software are you observing that runs 24 hour a day?

Comment: essentially only the operating system which is windows in this case

Comment: energy consumption in joules is only meaningful over a time span - minutes, hours, seconds? It would be useful to know what the system was doing minute by minute, was it indexing the file system every 2 hours on a timed job for instance? If it's just for academic purposes, it might be easier to use an easier to query OS like Linux.

Comment: We are aware the y axis does not make much sense right now :). But thanks for the input, we had not thought about it being scheduled job for some reason, with a bit of research we can see that windows defender and Disk defragmentation both run every 2 hours approximately

Comment: You are correct that linux is much easier to work with, but one of the goals in the paper is to compare the two operating systems

Comment: "Thank you for considering our question" - I can't actually see one.

Comment: Typical difference between load and idle on a PC is a factor of 5-20x. Your benchmark increases it by 1.1x, which doesn't seem plausible. How are you doing these measurements? Are you sure they're correct? Have you done any validation to check that your data is correct?

Comment: Several power saving features of the bios have been disabled, so that the computer will not change its c-states, this will raise the idle consumption considerably. But does not explain the trend we see

Comment: @JeppeHolt Did you find out any more about what was going on?

Comment: @pdb5627 Yes, we made several more measurements on both workstations, on both linux and windows, weekends and working days. All where very consistent in that they began to fall in energy consumption around 16-17:00, also the weekends.. The weekends showed the same trend, but to lesser degree,(we believe because there a fewer people working in the weekends). We also observed towards the end of the semester that the working days started to look more like the weekendes, because fewer people were working. Based on this we are conviced that the changes are correlated with the amount of people.

Comment: This is however hard to definitively prove, because we lack numbers on the amount of people at the institute. If this is specifically caused by the reactive energy is also up in the air, we believe it is likely explanation, but as we neither have the equipment or expertise to make conclusion about it, we have left it up for interpretation

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit ambiguous, but as I understand, you're measuring the power draw of a PC over 24 hours, and noting a higher consumption during the daytime? Are you using a laptop or any other computer where the monitor power is also measured (ie an extension cord)? In which case it may be auto-brightness maintaining a higher power in daytime ambient light, and a reduced power consumption at night.

Comment: It is a workstation with not external connections, the internet, keyboard and mouse are not connected. The pc is prevented from entering sleep, but besides that it just idles the whole 24 hours. The same trend has been observed on multiple workstations and across operating systems